# Show price based on the variant in Node and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a product table in database tbl_products where I show list of products (refer below image) now my default variant is 1 KG now i want to implement different variant for same product such as (500g,250g and so on) so as you can see mrp table i would like to show different mrp price based on different variant.Any way to do that?
[image]

Node code to display all products.So i need to change the database structure or modify my code?

```
module.exports.list = (icondir, callback) => {
    conn.query(`SELECT productId,productCode,categoryId,subCategoryId,productName,productImg,mrp,sellingPrice,variant,percentageOff,isTopSelling,isAvailable,productFeatures,productDescription FROM tbl_products where isDeleted=0`, (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, row);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to change the structure of your database in my opinion. Sometimes the price of 500g product is not kept as half of the price of 1kg product (for example price of 500g can be 40rs and price of 1kg would be 70rs), this is done to encourage the buyer to purchase more (a very common marketing strategy). In the above case, you will not be able to achieve the desired behaviour with any computation or modifying your code. Also you might need to perform computation at multiple points in your application. So you are better off changing your database structure.

You can create a separate collection for (productId,variant,mrp,sellingprice etc) which contains mrp for different variants to reduce the redudancy in your database.